# Remove/stop active class from parent when child class within div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="ticket-selector active">
    <p>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#ticket-panel" href="#collapseOne" class="tickets-more"><span class="halflings info-sign orange"></span></a>
    </p>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse in" style="height: auto;">
        <p>
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, when the "`.ticket-selector`" div is clicked it becomes active. Inside the Div there is a child class that triggers an accordion, the class is "`.tickets-more`". However, when this child element is clicked I do not want the parent to be active. Anywhere else in the div is ok to show the active class on parent but just not the child class.

Comment: [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Is `tickets-more` a direct child of the active div? Since it's not present in your demo code.
Ah Fiddle would be nice as well.

Comment: Thanks all. This does stop the active from appearing, but it also stops the .collapse from becoming .collapse in - basically the accordion stops working (child class). Its bootstrap accordion - http://goo.gl/TOcMzT

Comment: $('.tickets-more').click(function(){
   event.stopPropagation()
$(".collapse").addClass("in");

});

Comment: The above opens all of the childrens accordions up

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code in your onClick event handler for child element,

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

The event handler should receive a parameter

```
...click(function(e){ ...
```

Then use that parameter as the event

```
e.stopPropagaiton();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ticket-selector').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if( $(this).parent().hasClass('active') )
{$(this).parent().removeClass('active');}